# Privacy Policy Snippet for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, privacy-policy

I once saw a content block snippet from Google that can be incorporated into our Privacy Policy on our website with certain disclaimers surrounding Google Analytics.

Does anyone know where that is located or do you have a link to that content block? I can't seem to find it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find examples in most Privacy Policies nowadays.

What's important is to:

- Disclose the use of Google Analytics
- Inform users about the use of cookies by Google Analytics
- Inform users how they can opt-out from Google Analytics tracking. Preferably link to Google's Privacy Policy and their browser add-on that users can use to opt-out.

  You can find the tool here: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=en

For example, DaveMulder.com describes how he went about the required clause in a [blog post](http://www.davemulder.com/2010/07/01/using-google-analytics-wheres-your-privacy-policy/). His website's Privacy Policy [details the use](http://www.davemulder.com/privacy-policy/) of Google Analytics:

[image]

Northern also [has a clause](https://www.northern.co/privacy-policy/) on the use of Google Analytics in their Privacy Policy:

[image]

Comment: This is great @TermsFeed. Thanks